# How to get File/Files create by Spark df.write?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, amazon-emr

I have requirement to capture the parquet files created as the outcome of a `df.write.parquet("s3://bkt/folder", mode="append")` command.

I am running this on AWS EMR pyspark.

I can achive this using awswrangler using `wr.s3.to_parquet()` but this is not really fit for my EMR spark use case.

Is there such functionality ?

I want list of the files from s3://bkt/folder which spark wrote

Thx all

Comment: you want list of the files from s3://bkt/folder which spark wrote?

Comment: Yes that is is .

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of files that spark wrote to particular S3 path you can use either of below approach:

Use input_file_name which will give file path from which the record is originating from and do a distinct operation by selecting `filename`:

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
df=spark.read.parquet("s3://bkt/folder")
df.withColumn("filename", input_file_name())
```

Or you can use boto3 to list the files :

```
from boto3 import client

conn = client('s3')  # again assumes boto.cfg setup, assume AWS S3
for key in conn.list_objects(Bucket='bucket_name')['Contents']:
    print(key['Key'])
```

Comment: yeahh ,, nahh - i have a very high latency system with millions and millions of objects. This exactly what i want to avoid, having to do s3 list

Comment: ok what about the input_file_name approach in pyspark?

Comment: i already have the input file names , i am interested in the output files.

Comment: I am talking about reading the data you wrote using spark and then do input_file_name after you finished writing

Comment: this gives me the input files used and not the generated file

Comment: can you update your full script in your question?